# getent passwd when nsswitch passwd setting is: files ldap

Tags: password, ldap, nsswitch

If `/etc/nsswitch.conf` has:

```
passwd:     files ldap
```

this line in it, and I do `getent passwd` will it first run down the `/etc/passwd` list and then go through every user in LDAP?  That seems to be what's happens.

I tried it on a Red Hat server and it was scrolling thousands of lines when `/etc/passwd` is only 36 lines.

Comment: What you describe seems to me perfectly normal. When you use LDAP, `getent passwd` will list all users (local + ldap)

Comment: Thanks, it's very possible that it is normal.  I am fairly new to using LDAP with Linux.  Previously I managed users using a configuration management utility.

Answer (score 2):

`getent` will return whatever the results are for whichever "database" you specify. It determines what backends to use when constructing this "database" based on the contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

`getent` lists its "databases" when you query its usage page, `getent --help`.

```
Supported databases:
ahosts ahostsv4 ahostsv6 aliases ethers group gshadow hosts initgroups
netgroup networks passwd protocols rpc services shadow
```

To my knowledge, there is no way to disable its behavior of providing all the results for the various backends that are configured in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

`getent` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf` are both part of the nss (Name Service Switch).

*Excerpt from nss man page*

> Each call to a function which retrieves data from a system database
>   like the password or group database is handled by the Name Service
>   Switch implementation in the GNU C library.  The various services
>   provided are implemented by independent modules, each of which
>   naturally varies widely from the other.
>
> The  default  implementations coming with the GNU C library are by
>   default conservative and do not use unsafe data.  This might be very
>   costly in some situations, especially when the databases are large. 
>   Some modules allow the system administrator to request taking
>   shortcuts if  these  are known to be safe.  It is then the system
>   administrator's responsibility to ensure the assumption is correct.
>
> There are other modules where the implementation changed over time. 
>   If an implementation used to sacrifice speed for memory consumption it
>   might create problems if the preference is switched.

#### Backends

There are a variety of these, too many to cover here. But suffice to say, there are backends such as `sssd` (sss/LDAP), NIS, and NIS+ to name a few.

So depending on which your system has specified in your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file, will influence what output `getent` shows when a given "database" is queried, such as `getent passwd`.

#### References

- [sssd - howto configure](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Deployment_Guide/chap-SSSD_User_Guide-Setting_Up_SSSD.html)

Comment: The sssd howto link is dead.

Comment: @GhostLyrics - changed link

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you just say `getent passwd`, it will list all of the users it can find in any of the databases listed in nsswitch.

Comment: only for the NSS providers that enable enumeration. For instance, with `sss`, you can disable enumeration for some domains.